# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/meta.json"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, actioncontroller

It is an application with more than one engine. I get this error but I can't find where it is coming from. There is no problem with the general functioning of the application. I've tried to find the problem but I can't. Seriously, it's very annoying to have something like this on the console.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/meta.json"):
  
actionpack (6.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
rack-contrib (2.4.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:23:in `call'
meta_request (0.7.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:18:in `call'
sentry-ruby (5.9.0) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in call'
sentry-ruby (5.9.0) lib/sentry/hub.rb:223:in `with_session_tracking'
sentry-ruby (5.9.0) lib/sentry-ruby.rb:385:in `with_session_tracking'
sentry-ruby (5.9.0) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:19:in `block in call'
sentry-ruby (5.9.0) lib/sentry/hub.rb:59:in `with_scope'
sentry-ruby (5.9.0) lib/sentry-ruby.rb:365:in `with_scope'
sentry-ruby (5.9.0) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
lograge (0.12.0) lib/lograge/rails_ext/rack/logger.rb:18:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: `ActionController::RoutingError` are raised when there are incoming requests for paths that aren't configured in your `routes.rb`. But it does not necessarily mean that the requests are coming from your application. Application on the Internet are getting request for non-existing pages all the time, from people trying to find security vulnerabilities. Are you sure the request is coming from your application?

Comment: One thing you could do is temporarily add a route  for /meta.json  to a controller, and from there  dump the request data. Perhaps that would give a hint of where it's coming from.